# Array dentro de Array

Tags: php, array, foreach, array-push

Boa noite,

Estou consumindo um webservice e pego os dados em json com cURL.
Tenho os dados armazenados na variavel $data.
O que eu preciso é o seguinte:

Vamos supor que na variavel $data tenha os seguintes dados:

```
$data = [ {"nome":"Edileuza","CPF":"009876543-00"}{"nome":"Cleuza","CPF":"123456789-00"} ]
```

Então como podem ver tenho o CPF dentro desse array.
Preciso consumir um outro webservice que pega o CPF e traz outras informações.
E com essas informações terei outro array que quero colocar dentro do primeiro array.

Não estou conseguindo pensar em uma forma de fazer isso mas creio que eu deva fazer um foreach na variavel $data. Abaixo vou mostrar o que penso que seria certo e se alguem puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

```
$ch = curl_init($link);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($data));

$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

---

Aqui é que não sei o que fazer

---

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

$cpf = $value["CPF"]

$link2 = "https://www.siteexemplo.com.br/ws/$cpf"

$ch2 = curl_init($link2);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$data2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);


$data2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($data2));

$data2 = json_decode($data2, true);

}
```

---

o resultado seria

```
$data2 = [ {"Endereco":"Rua 1"}]
```

Dai gostaria que o Endereço fosse para o array $data para ficar assim:

```
$data = [ {"nome":"Edileuza","CPF":"009876543-00", "Endereco":"Rua 1"}{"nome":"Cleuza","CPF":"123456789-00", "Endereco":"Rua 2"}
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: O "Rua 2" vem de onde? Pelo que vc mostrou, o $data2 só retorna "Rua 1".

Comment: Ola sam, o resultado Rua 1 vem da consulta, o segundo webservice faz a consulta 1 por um. Ai no final passei o resultado do loop do foreach que apareceria Rua 1 e Rua 2

Comment: No caso seria algo no final assim: array_push($data, resultado do foreach $data2) e continuaria o Loop até percorrer todo o array

Comment: Utilize desta forma: https://pastebin.com/dK8TVpFa

Comment: Valdeir, agradeço a ajuda. Seu código parece ser a solução porém não tem um foreach nele. por que tenho que percorrer o array $data pegando dos os CPF dos indices, são mais de 300.

Comment: vou tentar algo aqui e posto depois

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```
$data = '[{"nome": "Edileuza", "CPF": "009876543-00"},{"nome": "Cleuza","CPF": "123456789-00"}]';
$data = json_decode($data, true);

$novos_dados = []; //ou array(); dependendo da versao do PHP
foreach ($data as $key => $value){

    //$data2 = '[{"Endereco":"Rua 1", "Cidade" : "Minha Cidade"}]'; //buscar data2 do webservice
    $data2 = '[{"Endereco":"Rua 1"}]'; //buscar data2 do webservice

    $data2 = json_decode($data2, true);

    if($data2) {
        foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $val2) { //adiciona todos os valores de data2 caso este tenha mais de uma informação. Ex: [{"Endereco": "Rua 1", "Cidade" : "Minha Cidade"}]
            $value += $val2; //concatena os arrays - o mesmo que $value = $value + $val2;
        }
    }
    $novos_dados[] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($novos_dados);
```